# Using Case statement inside Join Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I achieve this? I am getting an error `incorrect syntax near between`

```
@STARTDATE, @ENDDATE, @CREATEDDATE -- INPUT PARAMETERS 

SELECT * 
FROM [DBO].[xxx] x
INNER JOIN [DBO].[yyy] y
    ON x.ID = y.ID 
   AND CASE WHEN @CREATEDDATE = 1 
            THEN x.CreatedDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE 
            WHEN @CREATEDDATE = 0 
            THEN x.ClosedDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
```

Comment: CAPITALIZATION is akin to yelling on the web.  I doubt your really want to be screaming your question out.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server does not treat boolean expressions as something that a `case` expression can return.  In fact, `case` in `on` and `where` clauses is to be discouraged.  And you can easily express this using more basic boolean operations:

```
SELECT *
FROM [DBO].[xxx] x INNER JOIN
     [DBO].[yyy] y
     ON x.ID = y.ID AND 
        ( (@CREATEDDATE = 1 AND x.CreatedDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE) OR
          (@CREATEDDATE = 0 AND x.ClosedDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE)
        )
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking Gordon, why would using a case be discouraged here?  I would have thought this is valid : (psuedo comment code):  case when @ createddate = 1 then x.createddate else x.closeddate end between startdate and enddate

Comment: The problem is, @Twelfth , is that a `CASE` *can* make a query non-SARGable. I wouldn't say, personally, they they should be discouraged, but more that they should be used with care. They can be cause for poor performance. Kind of like the idea that people say that `CURSOR`s are bad; they aren't provided that they are used correctly.

Comment: @TejaSwaroop, first of all, the sintax of a case when must be finished with end, which is not present in your query.

Comment: @twelfth: Even this line was throwing me the same error.  @ createddate = 1 then x.createddate else x.closeddate end between startdate and enddate. I was just being curious how does it work.

Comment: @TejaSwaroop - that's psuedo code...the @ variables are hard to put into comments.  If you format it correctly it should work.

Comment: @Twelfth if you're posting code in comments, you can wrap the text using the \` character. Doing so will put the text into a more friendly format for coding languages. For example "\`SELECT 1;\`" will show as `SELECT 1;`.

Comment: Thanks for the single quote comment, @Larnu. I've never needed it badly enough to look it up, but I've wondered and now you've spoon fed it to me. Appreciated.

Comment: @Twelfth . . . Basically, they are unnecessary.  Boolean logic already has `NOT`, `OR`, and `AND` and that is sufficient for most logical conditions.  Expressing something in `CASE` just expands the possibilities without adding very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM [DBO].[xxx] x
INNER JOIN [DBO].[yyy] y
    ON x.ID = y.ID 
   AND CASE WHEN @CREATEDDATE = 1 AND x.CreatedDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE THEN 1
            WHEN @CREATEDDATE = 0 AND x.ClosedDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE  THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END = 1
```